# Scroll to bottom (and forced reflow performance issues)

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom

I'm trying to use the vanilla JS to scroll to the bottom of a `div` (inside my scrollable webpage) upon receiving a message (WebSocket, not important). The message adds a new element `el` into the `div`, and I want the `div` to scroll to the `el`:

```
div.append(el); // or ...array
// clear div if too many messages here,
//  using while (childNodes.length > ...) firstChild.remove();
div.scroll...(el);
```

- Using `div.scrollTo(0, div.scrollHeight)` (edit: or `div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight`) would be fine, if it was not that unbelievably slow - I receive a lot of messages quite often, and it basically freezes the browser whenever I have to force reflow with `scrollHeight`.
- Using `el.scrollIntoView()` (edit: or its variants) is actually much faster (accumulated from brief uneducated profiling sessions, 20s of `scrollTo` and 0.6s of `scrollIntoView`, given relatively same load), however, my `div` happens to be inside a scrollable page, and `scrollIntoView` causes the whole page to scroll to make the `el` appear in the view. Basically, I want it to scroll to bottom of the `div` even off-screen (or achieve a similar effect).

Are there any other solutions to this problem, or is it possible to fix one of the top two variants?

---

UPDATE:

- Using `div.scrollTo(0, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER);` and similar works only on Chrome, not Firefox. Runs fast though (comparable to the 2nd solution). Similar variant `div.scrollTop = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` actually performs quite poorly for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try `div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight`:

```js
var contents = document.querySelector('.contents');
const before = new Date().getTime();
contents.scrollTop = contents.scrollHeight;
const after = new Date().getTime();
const diff = after -  before;
console.log(`Took ${diff} milliseconds`);
```

```css
.contents{
  height:200px;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
.section{
  height:197px;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="contents">
  <div class="section">1</div>
  <div class="section">2</div>
  <div class="section">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Running profiling for 10 seconds with same/similar messages, 2301ms on the line with scrollHeight (your method with =), and 24ms with scrollIntoView. Using Chrome, looking at time in Sources near the line. Forced reflow is a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.scrollIntoView(false);
```

This will take you to the bottom of the div.

Comment: Sorry, but scrolling the `div` into the view is not what I wanted.

Comment: If you meant `el.scrollIntoView(false)` (where `el` in the question represents the added message to the scrollable `div`), adding `false` (which represents the `alignToTop` parameter) doesn't solve the issue posed in the question.